# Dependency injection issue (bidirectional communication)

Tags: dependency-injection

I have `a` an instance of `A` and `b` an instance of `B`

`a` must be able to call a method on `b` and `b` must then immediatly call a method on `a` if some checks pass.

To achieve this I would have cyclic DI

```
public A(B b) { _b = b; }
public void CallToB() { _b.Method(); }
public void Method() { DoSomething(); }

public B(A a) { _a = a; }
public void Method() { if (SomeCheck()) _a.Method(); }
```

I know I could get arround this, using events and let `b` be unaware/independant of `a`. But it would feel wrong.

Note: I haven't seen an answer to this question where bidirectional communication was made possible.

Comment: And this is why it's best to avoid cyclic dependencies.. (if interfaces are used, then there is no cycle established between the implementations themselves - which, if done via IoC or other injection, are wired up 'outside' of the cycle)

Comment: Cyclic dependencies often indicate a design flaw - if you have control over these classes, I suggest extracting whatever common dependencies are in `A` and `B` into a third class so that both `A` and `B` depend on that class, rather than each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this issue by depending on interfaces instead of concrete types and then use property injection. Here is an example:

```
public interface IA
{
    void Method();
}

public class A : IA
{
    private readonly IB _b;
    public A(IB b){_b = b;}
    //...
}

public interface IB
{
    void Method();
}

public class B : IB
{
    private readonly IA _a;
    public B(IA a){_a = a;}
    //...
}

public class BCycleDependencyBreaker : IB
{
    private IB _b;

    public IB b
    {
        set { _b = value; }
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        _b.Method();
    }
}
```

You then use `BCycleDependencyBreaker` when you compose like this:

```
var b_cycle_dependency_breaker = new BCycleDependencyBreaker();

//Make a depend on this implementation of b that currently does nothing
A a = new A(b_cycle_dependency_breaker); 

//Make b depend on a
B b = new B(a);

//Now, let the proxy implementation delegate calls to the real b
b_cycle_dependency_breaker.b = b;
```