# Joining all the the classes in an application together

Tags: service, dependency-injection, architecture, service-locator

I'm building an application and I'm having trouble joining all my classes together.

I've read up on DI containers, service locators and the registry pattern and I figured I'd want one of them to hold all my objects. I know there are key specific differences between each one but at this point I'm not concerned about that, i'm interested in something very specific about how they work on the inside.

If I provide a basic example hopefully I can illustrate the issue I'm having..

So I have my container object:

```
container = new Container()
```

My container has 2 functions, get(key) and set(key, object).

So now I have 3 classes I want to store in my container, and I provide each one of them a container object so they have a bridge to each other.

```
obj1 = new Class1(container)
obj2 = new Class2(container)
obj3 = new Class3(container)
```

After that I set my objects within my container:

```
container.set('obj1', obj1)
container.set('obj2', obj2)
container.set('obj3', obj3)
```

The issue I'm having is in my constructor what I wanted to do was to set a variable to each class that I wanted, but the problem is, is that the objects haven't been set in the container when each constructor is run so nothing gets returned. It would look something like this:

```
Class1{
  constructor(container)
  {
    // Both of these will return null becuase as the constructor is run there's no key assigned to obj2/3
    obj2 = container.get('obj2');
    obj3 = container.get('obj3');
  }
}
```

I want something cleaner than holding the container object and directly accessing the container everytime I want one of the objects. I'd like everything set in the constructor.

The same question has been coming up when I think about how a DI container work. I know a DI container creates an object only if it doesn't already exist, but what if the DI container has dependencies on a class that hasn't been created which ALSO has a dependency on the class it was trying to create? It would reach the uncreated dependency, try to create that, but then that class also has a dependency on the class it was originally trying to create. How do you solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you injecting the container into your objects? If Class1 requires Class2 and Class3, then it should specify those as parameters in the constructor.

Comment: If Class1 requires Class2, and Class2 requires Class1 how do I go about passing the same object to both classes? When Class1 tries to create itself I can't pass the object of Class2 because it hasn't been created yet, if you ignore the container this illustrates the same problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: So you have a cyclic dependency? Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173027/dependency-injection-issue-bidirectional-communication

Comment: Why the question is "Joining all the the classes in an application together"? It confuses, looks like creating one big class

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yeah, I think that's it, I'll look into that thanks